# HTML5 didn't separate two object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

can't display two objects

```
this._formsServices.fetching(this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(post => {
          this.field = this._formsServices.form;
          let comma: any;
          this.field.forEach(option => {
            if (option.optionEn) {
              this.options = []; <-----
              comma = option.optionEn.split(',');
              for (const key in comma) {
                if (comma.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.options.push({ label: comma[key], value: option.fieldType });
                }
              }
            }
          })
        });
```

output console is correct but at HTML5 didn't display this always focus on the last object

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {label: "name1", value: "1"}
1: {label: "name1", value: "1"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
forms.component.ts:91 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {label: "name2", value: "6"}
1: {label: "name2", value: "6"}
```

Comment: could you make a Stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x78eho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are erasing the data in your `this.options` every loop. On the first loop you pushed this two values `0: {label: "name1", value: "1"}
1: {label: "name1", value: "1"}` on your array and during the second loop your are creating a new array `this.options = [];`. Delete this line and should work.

Comment: But I need display 2 objects like console. Can you give me another solution ?

Comment: If your `options` is filled, you can loop in your template in order to render every values in your array.

Comment: If I remove `this.options = [];` will concat two object at one object :(

Comment: So, create two distinct objet.